# How can I make loading dots animation in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I only want a bit help from anyone or anywhere to make loading dots animation in a RichTextBox, like "Loading..." and this three dots have animation for example removing dot by dot to be one dot and then add dot by dot to be three dots.

If anyone know how can i do it please answer below and thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to solve this task. For example, you can use Timer.

Please, try the following code:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int loadTick = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(loadTick)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = "Loading.";
                    loadTick++;
                    break;
                }

            case 1:
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = "Loading..";
                    loadTick++;
                    break;
                }

            case 2:
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = "Loading...";
                    loadTick = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Not the cleanest code with the switch case IMHO, if they want 4 or 5 dots the day after it will become even worse. You can simplify like this: 

    loadTick++;
    richTextBox1.Text = "Loading" + new string('.', loadTick);
    loadTick %= 3;

Comment: In the Tick handler you can write just: `richTextBox1.Text = $"Loading{new string('.', loadTick)}"; loadTick += loadTick < 3 ? 1 : -loadTick;`

Comment: Thank you very much my friend mr.peter, it's very helpful for me thanks for answer my question and thanks for everyone who want to help me.